# Crystal Reports will not render correctly

Tags: asp.net, iis, crystal-reports

I am trying to deploy a web application to a Windows 2012 Server, but the Crystal Report Viewer will not render correctly on the server; but it works just fine locally.

[image]

My web.config file has the correct crystal tags:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
        <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
            <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null"/>
            <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"></section>
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<businessObjects>
    <crystalReports>
        <rptBuildProvider>
            <add embedRptInResource="true" />
        </rptBuildProvider>
        <crystalReportViewer>
            <add key="ResourceUri" value="/crystalreportviewers13" />
        </crystalReportViewer>
    </crystalReports>
</businessObjects>
```

I am using:

- Crystal Reports runtime 13.0.14
- IIS 8.0
- Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after weeks of head scratching, bounty offering, and Googling, I finally figured out the problem. The Crystal Runtime was working fine, it was a browser-compatibility-CSS issue. I added the follow meta tag to the page, and now it renders just fine in IE.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Unfortunately, it still does not render properly in Chrome, but that's a whole-nother problem.

Comment: Hum, this does not seem like a good solution, as the browser will simply run in compatibility mode.

Could you try to simply put the link to your CSS just before the start of your HTML tag? Like:

<link href="~/style/ReportViewer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

PS: I will update my answer if this works.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. The crystal report viewer still rendered the report incorrectly. Exactly as in the screen shot.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that Crystal Reports, by default, uses your local printer settings to generate the report and the server might have different default page settings (I have no idea why this option is by default).

To correct the situation, open Crystal Reports, in the upper left hand corner select File, then Page Setup. You will see a section called "Printer Options", check the box "No Printer".

You will then see the page as it printed on server. Correct it and it will print identically on any server.

I hope it helps.

PS: You can open Crystal Reports directly from your IDE, like Visual Studio, by opening the report file (.rpt) and selecting this menu (see picture).

[image: Crystal Reports]

PPS: It is possible I did not understand correctly the question. I searched the web and found a good and accepted answer that solved a similar problem that many persons had. The name of the topic was 
*Crystal Reports not rendering when webpage is served outside of network*. Everything worked well locally but would not render when not local: http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/361109/Crystal-Reports-not-rendering-when-webpage-is-serv#answer2

The solution explained in the link is:

> Crystal report viewer is dependent upon the runtime engine
>   installation files for .NET Framework 4 (32 & 64 bit installs). These
>   assembly files don't get included in your .NET project.
>
> 1. Go to the `C\inetpub\wwwroot` folder on any machine that has either/or crystal report runtime engine installations. For my
>      purposes, I just went to the one on the 2008 server I'm installing on.
> 2. Copy the `aspnet_client` folder in the `wwwroot` directory.
> 3. Paste this folder in the website directory folder. I assume this would work with a web application that was created from a virtual
>      directory as well, just paste it into the virtual directory.

*(See full source on CodeProject.com by following the link)*

Maybe this link could help you, the problem seems to involve the same technologies you specified. Is that your problem? If yes, did the answer on the provided in the link worked for you?

If none of those anwers helped you, it is possible this problem is generated by a CSS conflict between yours and the Crystal Reports CSS. If that's the case (you could try by using only CR CSS and see if the problem persist), it's possible to correct it simply by  finding the conflicting CSS and remove it from your CSS.

If not, could you please be more specific about your problem, any new information would help me find the right answer for you.

Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: What do you mean by "Open crystal reports?" I have Crystal Reports runtime installed on the server.

Comment: The server runtime of Crystal Reports is used to build the report for the clients, from the server, but it uses a report file you built locally to generate it.

How do you open/edit the report? If you use Visual Studio, you should see a Crysal Report menu on top. Click on it. I will send a picture when I get the chance (see my edited answer).

If you use Crystal Reports (which is a standalone application), use the menus I mentionned.

 Sorry for the delay.

Don't hesitate to ask, if you have any other question.

Comment: PS: The report file should be in your website/project's folder, as a ".rpt" file. If you do not made this file yourself, you need to download the Crystal Reports standalone app or the Visual Studio plugin to be able to edit the file and change the settings I mentionned. You could also change the printer settings of your server to fit those of the report file, but you would need to know those settings (the guessing game isn't a good strategy).

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible cause of the problem may be Crystal Reports runtime is installed, but your application is not running under default web site.

Work around for the issues is to Copy aspnet_client folder from **c:\inetpub\wwwroot** folder to the new website root folder.

Entire Steps are discussed below :

**[Crystal Report Issue with IIS - ( bobj is undefined , Crystal report not displaying )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266049/crystal-report-issue-with-iis-bobj-is-undefined-crystal-report-not-display)**

More Reference :

[**Crystal report not working outside the network**](http://scn.sap.com/thread/2145012)