# ASP MVC Crystal Report Not Displaying Properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

After a day of searching i can't figure out why crystal report don't render properly on web browser... (font is always roboto, margin is not correct)

I already tried this
[Crystal Reports will not render correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712662/crystal-reports-will-not-render-correctly)

I am using visual studio 2013, IIS 8, crystal report 13

here is my sample code of loading cr report

```
 public ActionResult Test()
    {

        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
        rpt.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "Test.rpt"));

        Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        return File(stream, "application/pdf");

    }
```

Please help me guys..

Comment: Sorry, but we're absolute rubbish at reading your mind. Please post the actual code you're having trouble with. You know the drill: here's my code, here's what I expect it to do, here's what it actually does.

Comment: sorry, i added the actual code that i used.. @Martha