# Dropdown postback is not working on a single page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a asp.net application.  It has a page where i have a dropdown

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Tax Type</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_TaxType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  CssClass="form-control">
    <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>VAT</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>CST</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</div>
```

On the code behind , i have an event handler for this

```
Protected Sub drp_TaxType_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles drp_TaxType.SelectedIndexChanged
        If drp_TaxType.SelectedItem.ToString = "VAT" Then
            txt_VATCST.Text = "4.2% against form ""D1"" else 13.125%"
        ElseIf drp_TaxType.SelectedItem.ToString = "CST" Then
            txt_VATCST.Text = "2% against form ""C"" else 13.125%"
        Else
            txt_VATCST.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
```

But this is not working when i put this on server( only this page dropdown is not working). I checked the console to find any thing and i got the below error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bobj is not defined
```

this page has crystal report reference and crystal report is working fine, but the dropdown is not working. Any idea to resolve this????

Comment: put a breakpoint to see what's happening.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15007451/525251)

Comment: crystal report is working fine, my problem is with dropdown postback which is not working.

Comment: on development machine and local test server , it is working but on server it is not working, the client is using shared hosting.