# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'bobj' is undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, crystal-reports

This question might be asked many times but I have gone through all the possibilities and suggested solutions without any improvement. This is what I have done:

1. Uninstall and install the latest version of SAP report.
2. Add aspnet_client directory to the solution and rebuild the solution.
3. Modify the content of preview.aspx and change all the occurrence of 12.X.X to 13.X.X.

but Still I got the above error. In fact, this is the statement that it has the problem:

> bobj.crv.writeWidget({'cons':'bobj.crv.newViewer','args':{'id':'MainContent_CrystalReportViewer1__UI','isDisplayModalBG':false,'visualStyle':{'width':'687px','height':'914px'},'layoutType':'fitReport'},'children':[{'cons':'bobj.crv.newPrintUI','args':{'isActxPrinting':false}},{'cons':'bobj.crv.newReportProcessingUI'},{'cons':'bobj.crv.newExportUI','args':{'canSupportRange':true,'availableFormats':[{'name':'Crystal
>   Reports
>   (RPT)','value':'CrystalReports'},{'name':'PDF','value':'PDF'},{'name':'Microsoft
>   Excel (97-2003)','value':'MSExcel'},{'name':'Microsoft Excel (97-2003)
>   Data-Only','value':'RecordToMSExcel'},{'name':'Microsoft Excel
>   Workbook Data-only','value':'RecordToMSExcel2007'},{'name':'Microsoft
>   Word (97-2003)','value':'MSWord'},{'name':'Microsoft Word (97-2003) -
>   Editable','value':'EditableRTF'},{'name':'Rich Text Format
>   (RTF)','value':'RTF'},{'name':'Character Separated Values
>   (CSV)','value':'CharacterSeparatedValues'},{'name':'XML','value':'XML'}]}},{'cons':'bobj.crv.newReportAlbum','args':{'initTabIdx':0,'displayDrilldownTab':true},'children':[{'cons':'bobj.crv.newReportView','args':{'viewStateId':'0','label':'Main
>   Report','isMainReport':true},'children':[{'cons':'bobj.crv.newReportPage','args':{'width':600,'height':800,'documentView':'PrintLayout','content':'\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n','extraCssFileUrl':''}}]}]},{'cons':'bobj.crv.newStatusbar','args':{'id':'MainContent_CrystalReportViewer1__UI_statusbar'},'children':[{'cons':'bobj.crv.newStatusbarBreadcrumb','args':{'values':[]}},{'cons':'bobj.crv.newStatusbarVersionIndicator'}]}]});
>   //-->

Can you please help how to get away from this error. I am using Windows 10 and VS 2012. My site is still in the development state so it is not yet in the server.

I tried all the possible answers provided attached but it did not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal Report Issue with IIS - ( bobj is undefined , Crystal report not displaying )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266049/crystal-report-issue-with-iis-bobj-is-undefined-crystal-report-not-display)

Comment: I tried all the suggestion in the link but all did not work.

Answer (score -1):

just follow the following steps to fix your issue
1.First of all Check IIS is configured or not in your machine if No then configured it first then copy the folder from bellow directory
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13
2. copy the crystalreportviewers13 folder and paste it in your project.
3. Give the reference of crystalreportviewers13 folder in your web page like

4.Build your solution, after successful compilation this error will removed from your solution.