# Report does not display on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, crystal-reports

I added a report to my project, when I run it in Visual Studio it works fine. When I publish and copy files from `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project12` and also copy the `aspnet_client` folder in `project12`, and open project12 from IIS, the report doesn't display.

These solutions did not help. What else can I do to fix this?

- [Crystal Report Issue with IIS - ( bobj is undefined , Crystal report not displaying )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266049/crystal-report-issue-with-iis-bobj-is-undefined-crystal-report-not-display)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef56f72b-7ede-47d8-ba9e-9e63b9ac0203/bobj-is-undefined?forum=vscrystalreports

Answer (score 0):

It's on the same computer? If you put it on other you need to install Crystal Report See [here](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/SAP+Crystal+Reports+developer+version+for+Microsoft+Visual+Studio+-+Updates+and+Runtime+Downloads) You need CRRuntime_XXXX.msi XXX depend on version you put CrystalReportforVS_XXX

Comment: But try to add the runtime... Perhaps the visualStudio package run only in VS

Comment: what i add ? @YannickIngenierie

Comment: Click on the link I give you in response, and in bottom of page you have a array, choose CRRuntime_XXXX.msi with XXX same like your Visual studio package :  CrystalReportforVS_XXX

Comment: i did not find this CRRuntime

Comment: i have visual studio 2013

Comment: which package you take to implement crystal report in vs

Comment: .. In array you choose V13.0.PackageNumber, and you download 32bit.msi or 64bit.msi.

Comment: Do you find the package?

Comment: but why i download this.. if website run on client this they there is no sense that we tell to client install this package :.

Comment: Perhaps but not for Crystal Report. U have free package for VS, and You have free RunTime to execute Crystal Report ousitde VS. It's sur, I use it several times to make quotation manager in PDF ...